# Using PHP syntax if/else if correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to have a web form use different times on the calendar based on if the form is a certain ID, if it is use the first group, if not use the default. I am hoping someone can help me here. I am a novice at php and intermediate at best in coding, I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
public function is_time_disabled($dt, $h, $m) {
$monday = 1;
$tuesday = 2;
$wensday = 3;
$thursday = 4;
$friday = 5;
$saturday = 6;
if (($form_id == 31)
return (
(($dt->format('w') == $monday && $h < 9) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h > 17) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h == 17 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h == 16 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h > 16))
);} 

) if else return (
(($dt->format('w') == $monday && $h < 11) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h > 18) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h == 18 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h == 16 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h > 16))
);
}
endif;))
```

Comment: Lines 1-6 of your functions are the same. It looks like you just want a conditional on the return. Your conditionals also are a mess. You are mixing every type of syntax PHP offers.

Comment: `if ($form_id = 31)` < that will always be true/equal to 31. You're assigning `=` instead of comparing `==` / `===`.

Comment: I am more so asking about how to properly have the IF run and then if not that form ID then do the ELSE and endif properly. The == all work as I need them to

Comment: Only define function once and put the `if` `else` inside it with the `return`s.

Comment: I just edited the question to hopefully reflect what you said, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

This could be optimized (alot) and this is just a pointer in the right direction using your existing code, one funtion and two returns:

```
public function is_time_disabled($dt, $h, $m) {
    $monday = 1;
    $tuesday = 2;
    $wensday = 3;
    $thursday = 4;
    $friday = 5;
    $saturday = 6;

    if ($form_id == 31) {   
        return (
        (($dt->format('w') == $monday && $h < 9) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h > 17) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h == 17 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h == 16 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h > 16))
        );
    } else {
        return (
        (($dt->format('w') == $monday && $h < 11) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h > 18) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h == 18 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h == 16 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h > 16))
        );
    }
}
```

If you anticipate adding other forms then a `switch` might be better.  If `$form_id` is not found in any of the `case` statements then `default` will be executed:

```
switch ($form_id) {
    case 10:
        //if the same as 31 then fall into the next one (no break no return)
    case 31:
        return (
        (($dt->format('w') == $monday && $h < 9) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h > 17) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h == 17 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h == 16 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h > 16))
        );
    case 99:
        //return something else
    default:
        return (
        (($dt->format('w') == $monday && $h < 11) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h > 18) || ($dt->format('w') == $friday && $h == 18 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h == 16 && $m == 30) || ($dt->format('w') == $saturday && $h > 16))
        );
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I am going to give this a whirl and see if it explodes the site shortly.

Comment: So the case X area would be to call the form ID correct?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Not needed for just 2 outcomes but for more than 2 it is very handy.

Comment: Well that didn't cause the site to explode but it still didn't work as expected, there has to be something else in these file overwriting that, in the first file of the settings it has this called, $form_id = 8; $scheduler_page_id = 7199; so i think that would be the problem. Any chance you do freelance work?